# External Files default location

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Mac with eclipse and I need to write a program that pulls data from .txt file and process it. I placed the txt file in /Users/MYNAME/Documents/eclipse workspace/working/Debug but I'm getting a message that the file wasn't found. Any suggestions for other default location?
I know I can specify the location in the code but I prefer to use the default one.
Thanx

Comment: _'but I'm getting a message that the file wasn't found'_ Show how you're opening the file actually, and what the message is please! Otherwise it's not possible to diagnose your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to put the file in default home directory as you can get the default home directory by using this function in C++: 
    char * getenv("HOME");

Comment: ... and you're guaranteed to have access rights for your home directory.